# Get REAL and IMAG from complex number in parsed equation

Tags: c#, symbolic-math, mathnet-numerics, math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

I am evaluating [Math.NET Symbolics](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/) for use in our application where we want a simple math parser for the user to calculate custom equations from our measurement data. Our data is in the form of [Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx) numbers.

To test I use the following code-snippet in LINQPad:

```
var complexA = new Complex(1, 1);
var complexB = new Complex(1, 2);
var symbols = new Dictionary<string, FloatingPoint>()
    {
        { "a", complexA },
        { "b", complexB }
    };

Evaluate.Evaluate(symbols, Infix.ParseOrUndefined("1/(a*b)+cos(b)")).ComplexValue.Dump();
```

This works great, but the following operators I could not find:
**How can we get the REAL or IMAGINARY part of the symbols?**

I tried `real(b)` and `imag(b)`, but that did not work.

As a workaround I could also do the following, but I would prefer an operator like `abs(b)` gets me the magnitude:

```
var complexA = new Complex(1, 1);
var complexB = new Complex(1, 2);
var symbols = new Dictionary<string, FloatingPoint>()
    {
        { "a", complexA },
        { "b", complexB },
        { "b_REAL", complexB.Real },
        { "b_IMAG", complexB.Imaginary }
    };

Evaluate.Evaluate(symbols, Infix.ParseOrUndefined("1/(a*b)+b_REAL")).ComplexValue.Dump();
```

P.S.: Bonus points for an operator to get me also the phase without calculating it manually.

Comment: As far as I know, this is just not supported. Here is the list of supported functions: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/blob/master/src/Symbolics/Symbols.fs. And here is the issue about extensibility of that library (allow adding more functions without modifying source): https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/issues/8 which is 2 years old